# Python: List comprehension to create a list strings of n-size maximum from list of strings of random size

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

The idea is to create a list of strings of a certain amount of characters preserving the order from the original list. The challenge is to accomplish it using only list comprehensions.

```
list_string = [ "aaa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
str_len = 6
[some_list_comprehension]
```

The result should be something like `["aaabb", "ccddee"]`. The string `aaabb` in the result list is 5 characters long, while the string `ccddee` is 6, that is because strings in the original list cannot be chunked. The order of the strings is relevant while creating the result, but irrelevant in the result, so that the end list could be `["ccddee", "aaabb"]` but not `["eeddcc", "bbaaa"]`. Each string appears in the result list just the same number of times as in the original, meaning that all possible combinations of the strings is not really the objective in this problem, mostly because each string in the result list is created following the order in the original.
**There are only 2 possible outputs**:

```
["aaabb", "ccddee"]
```

or

```
["ccddee", "aaabb"]
```

Comment: This question was answered moments ago so why did you create this one? ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476711/python-strings-of-certain-length-from-list )

Comment: This sounds specifically like homework of some kind.  Is that the case?  What have you tried?

Comment: "The string `aaabb` in the result list is 5 characters long, while the string `ccddee` is 6, that is because strings in the original list cannot be chunked." Using only list comprehensions for this seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: @SimeonVisser i posted a different question about strings and lists. this one has a very important difference.

Comment: do you want only results that are as long as the given `str_len`?

Comment: @g.d.d.c well i can actually accomplish it, but i would like to use a list comprehension. i'm pretty sure there must be a way

Comment: @Claudiu yes, in this case the results should be 6 characters maximum, but could be between 1 and 6

Comment: so to rephrase your question, you want to chunk the strings in the list such that each single string only appears once, and the length each combined string is less than `str_len`?

Comment: @Claudiu more less, only that no string in the original list can be chunked

Comment: @XianJacobs: what do you mean by `chunked`? you mean split into two?

Comment: exactly. strings in original list cannot be splitted, only joined to form strings of maximum characters long indicated by the variable `str_len`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it, now. Is this what you were looking for?

```
>>> list_string = [ "aaa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
>>> str_len = 6
>>> [[''.join(list_string[:i]), ''.join(list_string[i:])] for i in xrange(len(list_string)) if all(1 <= len(s) <= str_len for s in [''.join(list_string[:i]), ''.join(list_string[i:])])]
[['aaabb', 'ccddee']]
```

It yields all possible combinations that might have worked with one partitioning of the string. Here are all possible results:

```
>>> for str_len in range(len(''.join(list_string))):
        print str_len, [[''.join(list_string[:i]), ''.join(list_string[i:])] for i in xrange(len(list_string)) if all(1 <= len(s) <= str_len for s in [''.join(list_string[:i]), ''.join(list_string[i:])])]


0 []
1 []
2 []
3 []
4 []
5 []
6 [['aaabb', 'ccddee']]
7 [['aaabb', 'ccddee'], ['aaabbcc', 'ddee']]
8 [['aaa', 'bbccddee'], ['aaabb', 'ccddee'], ['aaabbcc', 'ddee']]
9 [['aaa', 'bbccddee'], ['aaabb', 'ccddee'], ['aaabbcc', 'ddee'], ['aaabbccdd', 'ee']]
10 [['aaa', 'bbccddee'], ['aaabb', 'ccddee'], ['aaabbcc', 'ddee'], ['aaabbccdd', 'ee']]
```

EDIT: Here is a version which uses `filter` but doesn't duplicate the result twice in the expression, and has nicer formatting:

```
>>> filter(
        lambda res: all(1 <= len(s) <= str_len for s in res),
        [[''.join(list_string[:i]), ''.join(list_string[i:])]
         for i in xrange(len(list_string))])
[['aaabb', 'ccddee']]
```

Comment: Thanks to your question I decided that this must be what the OP was after (modulo a possible permutation which he should be able to do himself), and so deleted mine as answering a different question.

Comment: sweet. can i ask what you are trying to do? hah. the only thing i don't like about my answer is i have to duplicate the result twice so i can filter it. EDIT: answer edited to avoid that, but it does use `filter` and not _only_ list comprehensions..

Comment: @Claudiu well by now this is the best solution. it is to create urls of certain size using strings in a list

Comment: hah! not exactly, the problem is that this list contains many strings, used to create the url, which would be pretty long, that's why the data has to be grouped in strings with a certain amount of characters long

Comment: ahh encoding some data in seemingly-innocuous urls? good stuff sir =).

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations
list_string = [ "aaa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
minn=min(map(len,list_string))
maxx=max(map(len,list_string))
str_len=6
lis=[''.join(x) for i in range(1,maxx+1) for x in combinations(list_string,i) if len(''.join(x))<=str_len]        
print lis
```

**output:**

```
['aaa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'aaabb', 'aaacc', 'aaadd', 'aaaee', 'bbcc', 'bbdd', 'bbee', 'ccdd', 'ccee', 'ddee', 'bbccdd', 'bbccee', 'bbddee', 'ccddee']
```

Comment: this doesn't only use list comprehensions

Comment: @XianJacobs solution edited, is this is what you're looking for?